# Reject calls from the iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to programatically reject a Phone call, and then save that number temporally in the phone.

I did a research and found that Apple will not allow this, but i am not going to release it to the app store.

How can i get this done ?

Comment: Apple will not allow this, but it would be possible with a jailbreak. You may not get an answer you are looking for here but if you are interested in Jailbreak development you should consider supporting the [iOS Jailbreaking Development proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?referrer=v3HFF-ebzgSz6aewN1cCiQ2).

Comment: but can i save the number that was rejected or called in the phone, and reuse it later ? (without having to jailbreak the phone)

Comment: Without jailbreaking/undocumented APIs the only thing you have access to is available in the [CoreTelephony.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603)

Comment: But, still i don't think i could get the users call records (rejected and answered)

Comment: No you can not,that is why I posted that link. That is all the access Apple allows you in a sandboxed environment. Until we get the [Jailbreak/Undocumented API proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?referrer=v3HFF-ebzgSz6aewN1cCiQ2) into beta you may have a hard time getting an answer.